# How to write a JSF component programmatically to response writer in custom component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm designing a custom component in JSF after I decided that the task to be solve is way too complicated for a composite component and started with the following approach:

```
@FacesComponent("offervaluescustom")
public class OfferValuesCustom extends UIComponentBase {

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("table", this);
        //a lof of code
        writer.endElement("table");
    }
}
```

I'm using PrimeFaces as JSF implementation and was wondering how I could write an element to the response writer programmatically instead of copying the generated HTML code which is a valid workaround, but not portable and an unnecessary repitition of work.

The reason I'm using a recursive component is conditional spanning of columns in some rows, but not in others, as well as difficult recursion which is trivial in `encodeBegin`, but complex in `cc:implementation` because of scope issues (render vs. view).

Comment: What is your exact goal? Whithin your "encodeBegin" Method, you should generate the HTML-Output required for YOUR component... and nothing more. The requirement to "include" other stuff is an indication, that a composite component might be the way to go! (They can have their own `BackingBean` and be referenced through their  own `taglib` as well...) Your example doesn't outline any needs for a custom Component.

Comment: @dognose I added an explanation to the question. I started a composite component approach, but I don't make any progress because of a large amount of issues (variables disappearing, i.e. being set to `null` and `""` without any logical explanation and no idea how to handle the conditional column spanning).

Comment: You miss to point out the concrete problem. Try to focus on your main issue (could be conditional column spanning?) and write a custom component that tries to fulfill this requirement. Forget about the rest of the problem (`//a lot of code` is something that a person who answers your question needs to guess). If you have some issue with that, you can post it here, but with a working example. Once you've got a basic component to get started it shouldn't be as difficult to port it to your case.

Comment: @dognose I get the point. It just seemed easier to implement a larger component as custom component, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170881/stackoverflow-in-jsf-composite-component-recursion in case you're interested.